# Copying Data Between 3D Numpy Arrays Where A Condition Is True

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, numpy, indexing

I'd like to copy data from one 3D array to another 3D array at the indices where a condition is true for a different 2D array. All three arrays have the same first two dimensional shapes (x,y coords).

I thought it'd be something like,

```
a[c == cond] = b[c == cond]
```

But in this case it is resulting in corrupted/garbled data when inspected. Is this the wrong way to go about this or is this the correct way and there is a problem with my code somewhere else?

Thanks!

Comment: Your array indices there will evaluate to `False` or `True`, which are equivalent to 0 or 1 respectively, every time.

Comment: @Cairnarvon The OP is using Numpy, so `c==cond` is still an [array of booleans](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html#boolean-or-mask-index-arrays). @Newmu, can you check whether that line is corrupting your data? It's as easy as adding a couple of print statements or starting pdb and setting a breakpoint...

Comment: Yeah, print statements found the issue, conflicting dtypes.

Answer (score 2):

If you are on a new numpy version, use `np.copyto`.

Answer (score 1):

If the arrays have the same shape exactly then you can do

```
import numpy as np
a = np.random.rand(4,5,3)
b = np.random.rand(4,5,3)
c = np.random.rand(4,5,3)
cond = c > 0.5 # for example
b[cond] = a[cond]
```

If, however, the shape differs over the last axis then you need to explain what you would expect to happen.

Answer (score 0):

Apologies, the array I was copying into had a different dtype and it was casting to that array's dtype instead of converting it to the original dtype. Fixed by initializing that array with the same dtype as the source array.

Comment: You have more freedom to deal with this problem with `np.copyto` which allows [several different options for recasting the type](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.copyto.html): `casting : {‘no’, ‘equiv’, ‘safe’, ‘same_kind’, ‘unsafe’}, optional`

Comment: np.copyto did not actually work in this case as the mask is evaluated on a 2d array while the copies are between 3d arrays with the same first 2 dimensions. Something about broadcast errors. It can work if I do a dstack before the make the 2d mask 3d, but that's kinda ugly.

Good to keep in mind going forward though. Thanks!

Comment: You could try `np.copyto(b, a, where=cond[...,None])` which adds one empty axis to `cond` of size `1`, so then the third dimension will be broadcast to all values for the third dimensions of `a` and `b`